# Python: Taking end 3 characters in a string from a user input

Tags: python, arrays, string, input

I have an algorithm which I want to run in Python. It wants me to get 2 inputs from the user, then extract the last 3 letters of each input, then output these 2 sets of extracted characters side by side. I know how to extract end characters from a given array but am struggling to work out the correct syntax for extracting end characters from a user input.

Got as far as...

```
fname = input("What is your firstname? ")
flength = len(fname)
sname = input("What is your surname? ")
slength = len(sname)
```

...understanding that I need to know the length of the input to find the last 3 characters of it...

`for x in range(flength):print(flength)`

...then tested the loop runs for the exact length of the input, so far so good, but the next syntax I would usually use are ones for an array. Can an input be converted into an array perhaps? Is there an easier way to achieve this I am overlooking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the length, nor use a loop, use the slicing notation on strings    `str[start:end:step]`

Along with negative indices, to start from end

```
fname = input("What is your firstname? ")
sname = input("What is your surname? ")
print(fname[-3:])
print(sname[-3:])
```

```
What is your firstname? johnny
What is your surname? Philivitch
nny
tch
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the slicing operation `[-3:]` to get the last three characters (`-3` in a slice means "three characters from the end"):

```
>>> print(input("What is your firstname? ")[-3:], input("What is your surname? ")[-3:])
What is your firstname? Daniel
What is your surname? Gough
iel ugh
```